# In SQLite3 how to group by those having no certain values?

Tags: sqlite

A table named "example" is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFIE7.png)

I would like to SELECT Name FROM example GROUP BY NAME. But at the same time, if anyone's value contains X, then that one should be excluded from the result. In the "example" table, A has three values and one of them is X so A should be excluded from the result. So does B.
The result produced by SQL clauses should be：

C

D

Could anyone help me write corresponding SQL clauses so that I can get the result I want?

Thank you!!

---

I tried to write something like this:

> SELECT Name FROM example WHERE Value <> X GROUP BY NAME.

It didn't work because A and B still have other values which prevent them from being excluded. I just have no idea of what else I can do. I'm very new in SQL.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free coding service

Comment: What I tried was: SELECT Name FROM example WHERE  Value <> X GROUP BY NAME. It didn't work because A and B still have other values which prevent them from being excluded. I just don't know what else I can do. I'm new in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparison results in either `0` or `1`.
So taking the largest result in a group shows whether there is a match in the group:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Example
GROUP BY Name
HAVING MAX(Value = 'X') = 0;
```